# Could not find property ´VERSION CODE´ en android (Boostrap)

Tags: android, bootstrap, android-studio

Bueno lo que quiero hacer es usar boostrap para mi aplicación android y lo que realice fue lo siguiente:

1. File
2. New
3. Import Module

Despues de que importe la liberia de Boostrap me salio un error que fue el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta el código de donde esta el posible error

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode = Integer.parseInt(VERSION_CODE)
    versionName = into  versionCode 1 versionName "1.0"
}
```

Pero no se que realizar porque el error no se ha podido quitar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solucion es muy simple, solo tienes que sustituir
`versionCode = Integer.parseInt(VERSION_CODE)`  por `versionCode = 1`

`versionCode` es el código de la versión de tu aplicación, necesitaras ir subiéndolo conforme vallas publicando actualizaciones en GPlay, **lo importante es que tiene que ser igual a un número**.